# updating complex nested object with mongoose in an atomic way

Tags: node.js, mongoose, acid

I need to do an atomic update on multiple nested documents in multiple parent documents in my DB; the scenario is as follows:

the model looks something like this (I will keep it short for sake of sparsity):

```
const productVariantSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    quantity: { type: Number, default: 0 }
});

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    ...
    variants: [productVariantSchema]
});
```

so, I have products that contain variants that contain the stock, when an order is placed I have to reduce the stock for the ordered variant, that is to say, that if someone orders multiple variants of the same product or multiple products and one or more variants of each the stock (quantity) needs to be subtracted accordingly. I would do this with a for loop normally (in memory), but in this case, the operation really needs to be atomic because the stock can be edited by the admin if a shipment of the product arrives among other things.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think this is the solution I was looking for; looking at the documentation i came to the conclusion that in this instance a transaction is needed. [Here is the documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html)

To sum it up, in my case i first need to get all the cart items and see if there is one product with multiple variants and if so I need to format that data accordingly so i can build my query objects later. This looks something like this (again shortened for the sake of sparsity):

1. the cart items that get posted to the api

```
     [{
            "productId": "ID here",
            ...
            "variant": {
                "variantId": "ID here",
                ...
                "variantStock": 160
            },
            "qty": 1
        }, {
            "productId": "same ID",
            ...
            "variant": {
                "variantId": "ID here",
                ...
                "variantStock": 160
            },
            "qty": 1
        }, ... ]
```

2. correlate the data for the product updates

```js
const uniqueProductIds = [...new Set(cartItems.map((item) => item.productId))];
const stockUpdateData = uniqueProductIds.map((id) => ({ productId: id, variants: cartItems.filter((item) => item.productId === id).map((item) => ({ variantId: item.variant.variantId, qty: item.qty, variantStock: item.variant.variantStock }))}));
```

so far, so good. I have everything I need for this to work. In my specific case I first change things in the database then charge the customer so if anything goes wrong in the database I just don't charge and notify the user of the error among other things. This is where the transaction from the documentation above comes in. Since I need to first create the order then all the stock accordingly the only way I can be sure that this will follow the ACID principles is with a transaction.

So i just make a session object, call `withTransaction()` method and create the order and update all the product variant stock from the shopping cart correlated data. If all of this goes good I just charge the customer and add the payment id to the order with a simple update.

Upon testing this it seems to be working as intended, but if anyone has a better or a more simple idea I would love to hear bout it. Also, any **constructive** **criticism** is quite welcome!